# are there any different levels of synchronization?

Tags: java, synchronization

I have heard that there are different levels of Synchronization.are there?(If there are ,would you please explain them with a snippet code?)thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Before Java 5 there was only one: the `synchronized` keyword. This waited for and obtained an exclusive lock on the reference object. When applied to a function:

```
public synchronized void doStuff() { ... }
```

the object being synchronized on is `this`.

Java 5 added a lot of concurrency utils, one of which was the [`Lock`](http://72.5.124.55/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) object. There are several versions of this including a [`ReadWriteLock`](http://72.5.124.55/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). This is the only thing I can think of that you might be referring to.

The problem with `synchronized` is that its fairly crude. Done badly it can lead to deadlocks. The Java 5 utils allow non-blocking lock acquisition, timeout on lock acquisition and read/write lock support.

Answer (score 3):

You'd really need to explain what you meant by a "level of synchronization". Are you talking about the difference between:

```
public synchronized void foo()
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
public void foo()
{
    synchronized(lock)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

? Or perhaps between the above and using the locks from [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html)?

If you could give more context to what you've heard, we may be able to help you better. More importantly, what problem are you trying to solve that you think might need this information?

Comment: Just some where was written that there are some levels of Synchronization,I don't know what does it mean?and also i have heard some where from my teacher and he just had a point at it and he said nothing about those levels.[:-(]

Comment: @Johanna - where is "somewhere"?  Actually, I suspect you are confused and your teacher was talking about something completely different.  Anyway, the first person you should ask is your teacher ... or someone else who went to the lecture.

Answer (score 0):

*I am assuming OP is referring to synchronization of object used in multiple thread and not the keyword in Java.*

This is my understanding, after reading *Goetz*, of different levels of synchronizations in Java.

Lets assume we have a object that we have to use across 132 threads, which use *the* object continuously, purely randomly, over say 100 years.

```
abstract Class ICount {
int i;
String iString;
public void add(int i);
public void sub(int i);
public void synchronized print(){
  assert(i == Integer.valueOf(iString));
  System.out.println("i"+String.valueof(i)+" == "+iString);
   }
}
```

Now there could be different implementation which either by design or by carelessness, be thread safe at different levels.

1. Thread safe synchronization implementation : Guarantees that any java code, that doesn't use reflection to screw the object, using this implementation, will never hit assert.
2. Concurrent synchronization implementation : In addition to guaranteeing thread-safety, the author of this implementation tried to allow concurrent executions when possible, and also gave a shot at avoiding locks (contentions).
3. Thread unsafe synchronization implementation : Developer of this, at least knows his class his not thread safe, and requests you not to use this implementation unless you have exactly one thread.

If this were a real problem, the majority of the practical implementation falls in fourth category of 'synchronization', which is it works sometimes, and not documentation sufficiently to categorize in one of the above categories, and hence by default falls in fourth category.